# Handle multiple language filename for FileField in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-file-upload

Here a simple django model:

```
class File(models.Model):
    info = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True,blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files")
```

and I would like to save any instance so that the file's file name would be a persian file name.
this is my view:

```
class FileCreateView(CreateView):
    model = File

    def form_valid(self, form):
       self.object = form.save()
        f = self.request.FILES.get('file')
        files = [{
          'url': self.object.file.url,
          'name': self.object.file.url[6:],
          'thumbnailUrl': self.object.file.url,
          'info' : self.object.info,
          'size': f.size,
          'deleteUrl': reverse('upload-delete', args=[self.object.id]),
          'deleteType': "DELETE",
        }]
        data = {"files": files}
        response = JSONResponse(data, {}, response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return response
```

but when i want upload a new file with persian name , i get this error in my view:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

thank u :)